# powerset(all combinations) of a resultset in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerset

I need a t-sql code to get powerset of a resultset.

example input :

```
ColumnName
1
2
3

Example Output(one columns as nvarchar) :
1
2
3
1,2
1,3
2,3
1,2,3
```

Output set may contain duplicate values such as (1,3 vs 3,1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one and get full powerset.
Enjoy it.

```
--EXEC PowerSet 'A,B,C,D'
Create PROCEDURE PowerSet(@Members NVARCHAR(64))
As
Begin
    Declare @SubSet NVARCHAR(Max),
            @SubSetCount int,
            @Counter1 int,
            @Counter2 int,
            @ID int
    Create table #Members
    (
        ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        Member NVARCHAR(50)
    )
    Create table #PowerSets
    (
        SubSet NVARCHAR(50)
    )
    -- Start Convert @Members To Table #Members
    Set @Members=@Members+','
    While @Members<>''
    Begin
        Insert Into #Members(Member) 
        Values(Left(@Members,CHARINDEX(',',@Members)-1))
        Set @Members=RIGHT(@Members,LEN(@Members)-CHARINDEX(',',@Members))
    End
    -- End Convert @Members To Table #Members
    -- Start Calculat PowerSet
    Set @SubSetCount=POWER(2,(Select Count(*) From #Members))
    Set @Counter1=0
    while @Counter1<@SubSetCount
    Begin
        Set @Counter2=@Counter1
        Set @ID=1
        Set @SubSet='{'
        While @Counter2>0
        Begin
            If CONVERT(char(1), @Counter2 % 2)=1
                 Set @SubSet=@SubSet+iif(@SubSet<>'{',',','')+(Select Member From #Members Where ID=@ID)
            Set @Counter2 = CONVERT(int, (@Counter2 / 2))
            Set @ID=@ID+1
        End
        Set @Counter1=@Counter1+1
        Insert into #PowerSets(SubSet) values(@SubSet+'}')
    End
    -- End Calculat PowerSet
    Select *
    From #PowerSets
    Order By Len(SubSet),SubSet
    Drop Table #PowerSets
    Drop Table #Members 
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you wanted to get a powerset of a table called @items with a single column named name.  You could get the powerset like this.  Change the table name, column names and column types as needed.  If you wanted to get each subset as a single row then just group by sk.k at the end

```sql
declare @itemKeys table(
    Name varchar(255),
    K int
)
insert into @itemKeys(Name, K)
select Name, POWER(2,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Name)-1)
from @items

declare @setKeys table(
    k int
)
insert into @setKeys(k)
select TOP(POWER(2,@n)) RANK()OVER(ORDER BY object_id)-1 as k
from sys.all_objects

select sk.K as SetKey, ik.Name
from @setKeys sk
join @itemKeys ik on ik.K & sk.K = ik.K
order by sk.K, ik.K
```