# Finding a Combination of values with inclusion list

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given a column of values ('Black', 'White', 'Orange') with sequence numbers 1,2,3 respectively, i need to find the permutations and combinations such as below.

[image: Example]

> Colortable     Color  Sequence
>
> Black 1
>
> White 2
>
> Orange    3    ColorCombi table with 2 columns     In           NotIn
>
> Black White, Orange
>
> White Black, Orange
>
> Orange    Black, White
>
> Black, White  Orange
>
> Black, Orange White
>
> Orange, White Black
>
> Black, White, Orange  Null

Comment: Hello priya, I would like to help but I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. Would it be possible to elaborate more, or give a simple example with an expected outcome ? It would also be helpful if the question could be formatted in a more readable way.

Comment: Yes, Sample data and required output including your try will be more useful

Comment: This is a Powerset, so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36859361/powersetall-combinations-of-a-resultset-in-t-sql would solve it.

Comment: I am sorry if I didn't clarify well before, I need a include and exclude list as shown in the example above. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky to do.  You can do it with a recursive CTE:

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('Black', 1), ('White', 2), ('Orange', 3)) v(color, seq)
     ),
     combos as (
      select cast('' as varchar(max)) as ins, cast('' as varchar(max)) as outs, 0 as seq
      union all
      select c.ins + v.ins, c.outs + v.outs, c.seq + 1
      from t cross apply
           (values (',' + t.color, ''), ('', ',' + t.color)) as v(ins, outs) join
           combos c
           on t.seq = c.seq + 1
     )
select top (1) with ties stuff(ins, 1, 1, '') as ins, stuff(outs, 1, 1, '') as outs
from combos
order by seq desc ;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=af7f625537462a52086333d9388aa921) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I tried a more generic one with dynamic sql, as the number of rows might keep changing. your answer helped in thinking in those lines:)

Comment: @priya . . . This should work for other tables.  There is no need for dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yes, this works as well.. thanks again for your help.